# Expresso Store: Add PDF attachement to order confirmation emails

Tags: expresso-store, email, 2.8

Is it possible to add an attachment to the order confirmation email in expresso store?

The attachment is just a generic terms and conditions type thing. So will be the same for all orders.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create an extension if you wanted to include the PDF as an attachment.

I have done something similar in the past with [PDF Press](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pdf-press) and a link in the email that when clicked would direct to a specific template (using the order hash) that would create the PDF and start the download.

Comment: hello. the pdf just contains legal gubbins so it'll be the same for all users. thanks

Comment: Ahhhh I misunderstood your question, but you would still need to create an extension to actually attach the pdf to the email.

Comment: I've updated my question to include this nugget of info!